# Why pdftk produced pdf files will not render in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, pdf-generation, pdftk, pdf.js

I have a site - www.jcrocetta.com.
On this site I have 2 pdf files. One file has blurred data and the other is clear, both files were created with pdftk.

In order to blur out some personal data in the pdf I used Inkscape. But Inkscape only opens/edits one PDF page at a time. After I made my edits in Inkscape I saved the files as .pdf formatted files. At that point I had three separate pdf files, pages 1 through 3. I then used pdftk to concatenate the 3 files into one.

The final pdftk-produced files are on www.jcrocetta.com. Just click the public information button.

In Chrome viewing inline works fine.
Downloading the file from Firefox works fine too.
But viewing inline on Firefox it renders blank pages. How can I fix this?

Also, I know that pdf files **not produced with pdftk** will render correctly on both Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately you did not provide the original PDF, but looking at the inner structure of the PDF, your resulting PDF is very special. Its text content is printed by filling certain areas using patterns which in turn consist of XObjects containing the actual text. Maybe PDF.js does not support yet filling areas with such patterns.

Comment: BTW, while digging into the PDF it became appearant that your blurred out personal information still are completely contained in those patterns; anyone knowing his way around in PDFs well enough can easily extract the information. Standard text extraction routines, on the other hand, usually do not dig into pattern when searching for textual data; they, therefore, most likely will not find your data.

Answer (score 2):

FireFox has a lovely new feature: It now uses the PDF.js library to render PDF files, instead of calling out to an Adobe Reader plugin, or forcing you to save the file to disk. Unfortunately, it seem that PDF.js isn't quite perfect yet. A quick search shows that other people have the same issue, but the only "solution" I've seen offered boils down to "file a bug report at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues or https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=PDF+Viewer".

Also: Do the three individual PDF files render in FireFox, before you use pdftk to concatenate them?

Comment: Very interesting. I just tried a file before concatenation and it still doesn't work. Must be the Inkscape Save As that's causing the problem.

Comment: When I look at the properties of the file that works: Producer = OpenOffice Creator = Writer    Properties for the file that does not work: Producer and Creator = cairo 1.8.10     Both formats are the same PDF-1.4      Thank you Elchonon

Comment: The PDF.js project already has at least one open bug for rendering issues regarding PDF generated by Inkscape, but that shouldn't stop you from submitting your bugreport as well.